# listview in a custom dialog

Tags: java, android, android-studio, listview

Решил написать custom dialog.

Для начала создал основной стиль с фоном и поместил туда ListView

dialog_list_view_mod

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:background="@drawable/bac_dialog">

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/dialog_list_view_mod"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

Потом создаю диалог в котором хочу наполнить ListView списком через ArrayAdapter

```
   AlertDialog.Builder builderSingle = new AlertDialog.Builder(SelectUpdateInstall.this);
            builderSingle.setIcon(R.drawable.logo);
            builderSingle.setTitle("Select One Name:-");
            View view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.dialog_update_select_two, null);


            String[] x = new String[]{"AAA","BBB","CCC"};
            ListView lvDayOfWeek = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.dialog_list_view_mod);
            ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,x);
            lvDayOfWeek.setAdapter(adapter);

            builderSingle.setView(view);
            builderSingle.show();
```

Но после вызова этого кода, У меня приложение вылетает с такой ошибок

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ListView.setAdapter(android.widget.ListAdapter)' on a null object reference
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Искать вью-элементы нужно в созданном вью-контейнере:

```
View view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.dialog_update_select_two, null);
ListView lvDayOfWeek = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.dialog_list_view_mod);
```

Без ссылки на вью вызывается поиск в разметке активности.

Comment: Спасибо, чет как то не подумал об этом. Все заработало)